# How to make an ISO file from bzImage and initramfs

Tags: linux, iso-image, kernel

I have a bzImage file and initramfs file. When I run `qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel bzImage -initrd initramfs` it works fine, but I need an ISO file.

How can I make an ISO file from those?

Comment: Why do you need an ISO file?

Comment: @gronostaj i'm making my own distro, i actually did it with grub and i will answer it, but i heard there is also a bootloader called syslinux? how we can use that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did it with grub, first you need to make these directories `mkdir -p iso/boot/grub` copy the bzImage and the initramfs to 'iso/boot' and you need to download the grub [binary](http://littleosbook.github.com/files/stage2_eltorito), then copy the files:

```
cp stage2_eltorito iso/boot/grub/   # copy the bootloader
cp bzImage iso/boot/             # copy the kernel
cp initramfs iso/boot/             # copy the init file
```

Then you need to make a `menu.lst` file in grub directory `touch iso/boot/grub/menu.lst`, this file is for grub config, you should give the kernel and initramfs path:

```
default=0
timeout=0

title os
kernel /boot/kernel
initrd /boot/initramfs
```

Now you are all done!

You can create the iso file by using `genisoimage`:

```
genisoimage -R                              \
            -b boot/grub/stage2_eltorito    \
            -no-emul-boot                   \
            -boot-load-size 4               \
            -A os                           \
            -input-charset utf8             \
            -quiet                          \
            -boot-info-table                \
            -o os.iso                       \
            iso
```